# Chef data bag creation from a recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How to create a data bag from a recipe and avoid the exception when that data bag already exists?

The documentation shows that creating a data bag is done like this:

```
new_databag = Chef::DataBag.new
new_databag.name('unique_name')
new_databag.save
```

This works when the databag does not exist yet, but how to make it work if the databag already exists so it will not break the chef run?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the `list` method of Chef::DataBag and check whether your databag's name is present:

```
require 'chef/data_bag'

unless Chef::DataBag.list.key?('unique_name')
  new_databag = Chef::DataBag.new
  new_databag.name('unique_name')
  new_databag.save
end
```

I use this to make my recipes more robust, or throw a more friendly error if an expected databag cannot be found on a Chef server.

Comment: I think the "if Chef::DataBag.list.key?" test should be an unless. In that case you only make the new databag if it already exist to pass that test. Correct? Thanks for pointing out the pattern though :D